# How can I change wpf user content from other project

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

How can I change wpf user content from other project. For example I have two user control project. I want to change textbox in first user control project when clock tick in second wpf user project. Is it possible ?

First Project

```
<UserControl x:Class="StatusBar.StatusBarWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <StatusBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="0"  Background="{x:Null}">
        <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <TextBox x:Name="TxtClock" IsReadOnly="True" Background="{x:Null}"  BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Black" x:FieldModifier="public" Text="i want change" />
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
</Grid>
```

Second project

```
    DispatcherTimer clock = new DispatcherTimer();
TxtSaat.Text = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now);
clock.Tick += new EventHandler(Clock_Tick);
clock.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
clock.Start(); 
private void Clock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TxtClock.Text = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get an instance of the user control somehow. Given that, you can use this:

```
userControlInstance.TxtClock.Text = String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now);
```

Or you could give the user control a property:

```
private DateTime _displayTime;
public DateTime DisplayTime
{
    get { return _displayTime; }
    set { 
        _displayTime = value;
        TxtClock.Text = String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", _displayTime);
    }
}
```

and from the outside world call

```
userControlInstance.DisplayTime = DateTime.Now;
```

The important part is: You need to have access to the instance of the user control.

Comment: Let me guess. You have a user control in the window and you created an instance in code using `... = new MyUserControl();` which you run the updates on and now the display is not updating?

Comment: Well, how do you think it should work? Of course you need to update the instance of the user control that's added to the window, not another one that isn't even visible...

Comment: In the code behind your window: what's the name of the user control? Try if you can access it from here through a variable. If so, pass that variable to the other code that's supposed to do the update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you face is caused in part by having program logic in a UserControl. That tends to make things a little more tricky. Ideally only things specific to the view should be in a UserControl, which ideally means just xaml with no code behind.

I would recommend making a non-view class where all the logic can be kept. Eg:

```
class ClockViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ClockViewModel()
    {
        ...
        clock.Tick += new EventHandler(Clock_Tick);
    }

    private void Clock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Tick = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now);
    }

    string _tick="";
    public string Tick
    {
        get
        {
            return _tick;
        }
        set
        {
            _tick = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Tick"));
        }
    }
}
```

Then your views can bind to the same instance of that class (just inject the same instance into their constructor or a property). Then in your xaml you can do this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Tick}"/>
```

And your textbox will be automatically updated on each tick. That way your logic doesn't need to know about TextBoxes or views in general. The problem then becomes how do you share the same instance of the ClockViewModel class between code in different projects? For that you can inject it in through constructors or property setters.